# How to access the items inside the result of my query?

Tags: entity-framework, ienumerable

here is a snippet of my code:

```
using (var uow = new UnitOfWork())
{
    //ItemType itself
    ItemType itemType1 = uow.ItemTypeRepository.Get(i => i.Name == "ServerTypeList").FirstOrDefault();
    Assert.IsTrue(itemType1.ID != null);

    var itemType2 = uow.ItemTypeRepository.Get(i => i.Name == "ServerTypeList", orderBy: o => o.OrderBy(d => d.Name), includeProperties: "Items");
    //itemType2[0].
...
```

I am trying to list all the items inside itemType2 ("Get" method returns an IEnumerable):

[image]

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with `itemType2.First().Items[0]`?

This works because `itemType2` is a sequence. Based on what you're seeing in the debugger, it has only one element. If it *always* has only one element, then you should use `itemType2.Single().Items[0]` instead.

Every element of this sequence has an `Items` property, which appears to be a list or array or something else that can be indexed, so once you get there, you can index into it, as above, or you can iterate over it:

```
foreach (var item in itemType2.Single().Items)
{
    // Do something with each item in the sequence
}
```